# Make text always appear orthogonal to the plane when rotating a cube

Tags: three.js

I'm creating text labels that appear on a 3D cube using the following pattern:

```
canvas = createTextCanvas(text, color, font, size);
texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
geom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(canvas.width, canvas.height, segW, segH);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, transparent: true});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);

mesh.position.x = x;
mesh.position.y = y;
mesh.position.z = z;
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

The labels and their positions get set within a `for` loop for each edge of the cube.  This results in labels appearing similar to this:

[image]

But then when I rotate the cube (using `OrbitControls`), you'll see that the label no longer appears vertically like above:

[image]

So using the `Cost` label as an example, I would want the text to remain vertically oriented whenever the cube is rotated.  Basically, I'm trying to mimic the behavior of axis labeling in VTK.

So I believe the solution here is to set the `up` vector of the label to a vector that's always orthogonal to the plane.  But I'm not sure how to implement this.  Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, I'm constructing the cube using a `BoxGeometry` and `MeshNormalMaterial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the label keeps moving with the cube or not?
If not, there is a example: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html. The label keeps  facing to you but may not vertical.
Else ,you may need a canvas texture,the label is a object just like the cube and you can set its position to keep it vertical.But it doesn't look good sometime.the example:http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html.

I think you just want the label always facing to you when you change your sight.